# The word "afterclap"

Tags: word-usage

Merriam-Webster defines "afterclap" as "an unexpected damaging or unsettling event following a supposedly closed affair." However, a pastor from Oregon, John Mark Comer, wrote an article about marriage in which he used "afterclap" this way:

> "Like millions upon millions of other Americans, I married for happiness.
>
> That sounds innocuous at first glance. Heck, it sounds romantic. But the trouble is that happiness is the result of a healthy marriage. It’s not the reason for marriage. Happiness is a great thing, but it’s the by-product, the AFTERCLAP of marriage. It’s not the point."

Read more [here](http://www.relevantmagazine.com/life/relationships/promise-you-cant-keep-marriage#a0K12TzL7VVJFqTa.99).

It seems that "afterclap", here, simply means "consequence". Happiness is obviously not an "unsettling or damaging event", so, basing solely from Merriam-Webster's definition of the word, "afterclap" is probably not the best word to describe happiness.

So, what is the definition and use of the word "afterclap"? Does it have a positive or a negative connotation? Was Merriam-Webster wrong? Did the writer of the article use the word correctly?

Comment: I'm just going to say that as a fairly well-educated native-speaker American, I've never heard of the word "afterclap" until reading this question. So, I would tend not to use it and would not apply any connotations to it.

Comment: This word is new to me and even in context it seems like a weird  combination. There's the common 'aftereffect' or more colorful 'blowback' which already exist. It sound like the person who used this is making a malapropism.

Comment: Did anyone else notice the rather cute pun on 'clap' (i.e. a slang term for gonorrhea) in the Merriam-Webster definition, "An unexpected damaging or unsettling event following a supposedly closed **affair**"?

Comment: I'd never heard it before, but the word certainly isn't new - 1633 old enough for you? In "The Tragedy of Orestes" by Thomas Golfe, is the following sentence: "Your father is come home: but being come, should now some wilful afterclap of fate but take him hence again, and cross your joy".

Comment: I've heard the term before, applied to thunder.  And I've actually heard an "afterclap" -- vaguely recalling it was in the mountains (which is not my usual environment).  There was a thunder crack and then maybe a second later a very loud echo which was quite unexpected and startling.  For people living in certain mountainous regions (probably the shape of the valleys is important) this is probably a familiar phenomenon and one that would come to be used metaphorically.

Answer (score -3):

You need to remember that in more recent years Merriam-Webster took a decidedly "descriptive" or observational approach to defining words than they had in the past when they first published Webster's New International Dictionary Third Edition in 1961. You can read about somewhat about that that in *[The Perils of Prescriptivism: Usage Notes and The American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.jstor.org/stable/455550?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)* by John Ottenhoff and published in *American Speech* Vol. 71, No. 3 (Autumn, 1996), pp. 272-284 by Duke University Press.

The preface of the third edition dictionary states:

> In conformity with the principle that a definition, to be adequate, must be written *only after an analysis of usage*, the definitions in this edition are based chieflly on examples of usage collected since the publication of the preceding edition.

One possible problem with this approach is that perhaps sometimes people can read too deeply in between the lines, and read more meaning into a word than it was ever intended to convey based upon the surrounding context.

I suppose that the probable reason "afterclap" has negative connotations by their definition is probably because the word is more often applied in negative scenarios, rather than the word itself directly having any connotations. This is reflected in The American Heritage Dictionary Fifth Edition's definition:

> An unexpected, often unpleasant sequel to a matter that had been considered closed.

Often is not always, but it's probably most of the time and even if it's not, it's probably at least often enough that Merriam-Webster wanted to note this.

Anyway I can't help but notice that the author of this article is a Christian or more specifically Pastor John Mark Comer. I believe this is relevant because serious Christians are more likely to defer to Noah Webster's [American Dictionary of the English Language](https://archive.org/details/americandictiona00websuoft) (A.D.E.L.) than other people.

This is in part, because they believe the definitions written by a pious christian scholar are less perverse than those found in any other and that its definitions are closer to the meanings found in the bible, especially since it makes copious use of biblical quotes. It's allegedly a favorite among preachers and biblical scholars.

Several websites dedicated to the dictionary try to appeal to christian sensibilities. https://1828.mshaffer.com/ <sup>1</sup> for instance has the following quotation from The American Dictionary of the English Language's preface  as a page header:

> In my view, the Christian religion is the most important and one of the first things in which all children, under a free government ought to be instructed … No truth is more evident to my mind than that the Christian religion must be the basis of any government intended to secure the rights and privileges of a free people.

http://webstersdictionary1828.com/ <sup>2</sup> also lists a few reasons they think it's one of the best dictionaries on their homepage:

> - Webster's 1828 Dictionary contains the foundation of America's heritage and principal beliefs. It is contemporary with the American Constitution.
> - Webster's 1828 Dictionary contains the foundation of America's heritage and principal beliefs. It is contemporary with the American Constitution.
>     It is an excellent reference for classical literature, Bible studies, history papers, and the ground work of explanation and reasoning for America's national documents.
> - Christian readers will find it rewarding to compare Webster's definitions of such words as: marriage, education, sin, law, faith, and prayer, with those given in any modern dictionary. The difference gives an appreciation of early American values.
> - A breath of fresh air in an era of political correctness and subjectivism.

The Foundation for American Christian Education even publishes a single volume facsimile of A.D.E.L. with an I.S.B.N. of 978-0-912498-03-4 which has information regarding why they think it's the best dictionary to use to teach your children if you need an offline resource.

*Hence I opine that it is **much more** likely that the writer of the article in question* is referencing *Noah* Webster's definition than *Merriam*-Webster's. This is important because Noah Webster's definition lacks any express mention of the negative connotations:

> '**After-clap**, n. An unexpected, subsequent event; something happening after an affair is supposed to be at an end. — A.D.E.L.

A slightly more astute reading might suspect "is supposed to be at an end" suggests negative connotations, although it can't be said with any certainty that this is what it meant. What I can say is that alongside it gives me good reason to doubt that the author of this article had negative connotations in mind if my supposition that the artice's author uses A.D.E.L. is correct.

So why are there no hyphens like in Webster's definition? Well, most people don't really use hyphens anymore: Spencer Kornhaber's  July 18th 2013 article *Jay-Z Joins To-Day and Ice-Cream in the Hyphen Graveyard for [The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2013/07/jay-z-joins-to-day-and-ice-cream-in-the-hyphen-graveyard/277932/) notes that between the 5th and 6th editions of *The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*, 16,000 hyphenated entries lost their hyphens.

However, it is *possible* that some negativity was meant. I would particularly like to note is that the happiness of marriage does seem to be seen in a slightly negative light by the linked article, in that it implies that the love for your spouse may overshadow your love for god, which is bad.  The quote "A spouse is not a substitute for God." stands out in particular. I also vaguely recollect that in The Book of Job, God killed Job's wife as a proof to Satan that Job's faith was exemplary and unwavering.

However in making this supposition, I should admit that I may be committing the very same error that I complained Merriam-Webster might be making. Just to make sure I'm not putting words into anybody's mouth and mitigate against potential hypocrisy, I'll include the article's disclaimer: "Don’t get me wrong. Marriage is incredible! But it’s not heaven on earth. It’s two broken people coming together to follow God’s calling on their lives."

---

<sup>1</sup> [1828 Mshafter's website mirror page on The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160812061137/https://1828.mshaffer.com/)

<sup>2</sup> [Webster's Dictionary 1828 website mirror page on The Internet Archive's Wayback Mchine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160812060815/http://webstersdictionary1828.com/)

Comment: I enjoy a good random screed, and love a spirited debate over prescriptivism; but... What?

Comment: @H.H.Rambler I'd have rather not said anything about that myself now, but it was unavoidable here. The introductory part also suggests that even by contemporary definitions, the word does not *necessarily* have negative connotations just because Merriam-Webster implied to be requisite. Also, the main point of this answer that the author's status as a priest makes him more likely to prefer one older dictionary over the other, so even if the given definition is archaic, he's more likely to use that archaic meaning than the common one. That's hard to prove, which is why the answer is so long.

Comment: 1) Why do you think an older dictionary (1828) would have an appropriate definition for usage for our time? 2) Why do you give links to the wayback machine when the actual websites work just fine now? Are you concerned about the government conspiracies (also neo-liberal NGO conspiracies) to hide what we really mean? I've said too much already.